# Excel Need to Check one Sheet for Data if True take data and paste in field

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, merge

I am doing inventory for my company but need to use last years inventory prices in this years quarterly spreadsheet. There are only 3 Information fields. SKU, Qty, and Cost. In the master it has SKUS from last year, the qty and has the Cost that was filled in then. In the quarterly It has SKU, qty, but all costs are empty. I want to take as much data from the end of year cost and only fill in what we didnt have last year.

I want every row to be checked in the sku row of my master if there is a match in the sku in my quartlery I want the data from cost to be moved for that sku in the master to the cost in my quarterly sheet. If it is not found just leave the quarterly cost blank.

How can I achieve this?